# jQuery Toggle Class Not Working

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/HzpR2nyCMr) and let me know why the `.toggleClass()` is not finctioning here?

```
$(function() {
    $("#cluster-box").on("click", function () {
       $('#cluster-info').toggleClass("fa-th-large fa-fax");
    });
});

<div class="container">
 <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm navbar-btn">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm navbar-btn">Middle</button>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm navbar-btn" id="cluster-box"> <input type="checkbox" id="cluster" class="hidden" checked=""><i id="cluster-info" class="fa fa-fax"></i></label>    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your click handler appears to be firing twice. So it is toggling on then off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every click, your event handler is being triggered twice. First for the checkbox and then bubbled up to `#cluster-box` as well. As a result, the classes are toggled twice and hence you see no difference.

```
$("#cluster-box").on("click", function (_event) {
    console.log('handler triggered!');
    $('#cluster-info').toggleClass("fa-th-large fa-fax");
});
```

Using a `console.log()` like above, you'll be able to see that the handler is getting triggered twice.

Instead of listening to `click` on `#cluster-box`, listening to `change` event on `#cluster` will solve this. [**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/ruOxoCMtYk)

```
$("#cluster").on("change", function (_event) {
    $('#cluster-info').toggleClass("fa-th-large fa-fax");
});
```

Comment: Great tahanks techfoobar,